# Interchange of limits

Tags: analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

I've done this test (Analysis I class)

> Let be
>
> $ f(x, y) = \frac{x^2y^2}{x^2y^2+(x-y)^2}$
>
> Then:
>
> a) $\lim_{x\to 0}\lim_{y\to 0} f(x, y) \neq \lim_{y\to 0}\lim_{x\to 0} f(x, y)$
>
> b) $\lim_{x\to 0}\lim_{y\to 0} f(x, y) = \lim_{y\to 0}\lim_{x\to 0} f(x, y) = 0$
>
> c) It doesn't exist $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0, 0)} f(x, y)$
>
> d) ...

I know the correct answer is c. In fact, f(x, 0) = 0 and f(x, x) = 1 for every x not 0, so the limit doesn't exist.
My question is: why it's not also correct b?

In class we have never seen these "double limits", so probably I'm wrong, but it's not true that

$\lim_{x\to 0} ( \lim_{y\to 0} f(x, y) )= \lim_{x\to 0} (0) = 0$

?

Thanks in advance,

Marco

Comment: I think you're right about b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the left hand side of a) and b) we first take limit in $y$:
$$\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{x^2y^2}{x^2y^2+(x-y)^2} = \frac{x^20^2}{x^20^2+(x-0)^2} = 0,$$
then in $x$ of the last result:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \lim_{y\to 0} \frac{x^2y^2}{x^2y^2+(x-y)^2} = \lim_{x\to 0} 0 = 0.$$

For the right hand side we first take limit in $x$:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2y^2}{x^2y^2+(x-y)^2} = \frac{0^2y^2}{0^2y^2+(0-y)^2} = 0,$$
then in $y$ of the last result:
$$\lim_{y\to 0} \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2y^2}{x^2y^2+(x-y)^2} = \lim_{y\to 0} 0 = 0.$$

Thus we se that a) is incorrect, and b) is correct.

Had the above limits not existed or had they been different (case a) then it had been clear that the limit in c) also had not existed. But now they exist and are equal so it might be the case that the limit when $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ exists.

However, as you already has noticed, if we let $x=y \to 0$ then we get limit $1,$ which is different than the other limits. Thus the limit as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ does *not* exist, i.e. c) is also correct.

Comment: So, both b and c are correct?

Comment: Yes, both b and c, but not a, are correct.